# Change element's ID multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so what I'm triying to achieve is that I want one element to append some other elements to div and change its ID attribute (or something similar).

i have tried something like this

```
$('#add3').click(function(){
            $('#add3').attr("id", "add4");
            $('.third_row1').append('something to append');
        });
```

and also tried something like this:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
            var vari = $("<div id='add2'>add another user</div>");
            $('#add').remove();
            $('.third_row1').append(vari);
            $('.third_row1').append('something to append');
        });
```

so clicking one button (like second example) has no effect on third, fourth ... n click
same thing with the second example

thanks in advance for help

**UPD**

ok, so here's how I generate selects which I want to append

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj1" class="com.Users" scope="page"/>
    <div class="third_row1">
        <select name="mySelect1" id="mySelect1">
            <c:forEach var="item1" items="${obj1.items}">
                <option>${item1}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
```

all I want to do is to add same select, but with different ids and names

Comment: please share your html code too and please explain the problem

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net. Also, **var vari = "<div id='add2'>add another user</div>";** (shouldn't have the **$()** around it).

Comment: Since elements IDs are dynamic, use delegated event handlers. For example, `$(document).on("click", "#add3", function() {`

Comment: @dwhite.me there is no error in using `$("<div id='add2'>add another user</div>")`. It will work just the same way.

Comment: @Regent post your comment as an answer, your advice resolved the problem, thanks

Comment: @YuriyKravets you're welcome. Since it is corrent one, I will post it in several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since elements IDs are changed dynamically, you should use [delegated event handlers with .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

For example:

```
$(document).on("click", "#add3", function() {
    $('#add3').attr("id", "add4");
    $('.third_row1').append('something to append');
});
```

If all these elements (`#add`, `#add3`) are inside page static element, it will be better to use this element instead of `document` for perfomance:

```
$("static_element_selector").on("click", "#add3", function() {
```

And just to note: since `this` inside event handler points to clicked DOM element, you can use `this.id = "add4"` instead of `$('#add3').attr("id", "add4");`. It is shorter and works slightly faster.